# How to determine the Publish source for ADFv2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When using a Git-backed ADFv2, I'm trying to detect when a user publishes directly to the Factory vs when a user publishes to the Factory via the Git collaboration branch.

I've tried looking at the Activity Log, but I can't distinguish between events from a Git Publish vs events from a Direct Publish.

I see that this information is at least visible in the UI. Is this persisted anywhere? Is there any way to obtain this message?

[image]

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: I'll have to see if there's any way to correlate a ADF publish event in Azure with the /publish branch being updated in AzDevOps.

Comment: Based on my research,you could only view the commits in the dev ops release page.

Answer (score 0):

According to my observation, the messages don't persisted anywhere.It is just temporarily stored in the browser's cache, and disappears once you refreshes it.

[image]

In the ADF active log,you only could see the epitomize of operations.

[image: epitomize]

I supposed that you only can distinguish between events from a Git Publish vs events from a Direct Publish in the Dev ops page.

You could see the direct publish will leave the comments in the commits list.

[image]

And if you release any updates in the Git publish, you could remark some prefix,like `--from git---`.

[image]